# Which files have SUID bit in bin/ folder

Tags: 11.04, privileges

Accidentally, I made a mistake with files in `/bin/` folder, and now I learned that some of it need to have SUID bit. Can someone please do `ls -l /bin/` and paste which files doesn't have `-rwxr-xr-x` flags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       6 Mar 10 15:57 bzcmp -> bzdiff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       6 Mar 10 15:57 bzegrep -> bzgrep
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       6 Mar 10 15:57 bzfgrep -> bzgrep
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       6 Mar 10 15:57 bzless -> bzmore
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root   26252 Mar  2 16:33 fusermount
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       8 Mar 10 15:57 lessfile -> lesspipe
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root   88760 Mar 30 06:49 mount
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Mar 10 15:57 mt -> /etc/alternatives/mt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Mar 10 15:57 nc -> /etc/alternatives/nc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   26152 Jul  1  2011 nc.openbsd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Mar 10 15:57 netcat -> /etc/alternatives/netcat
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       6 Mar 31 23:03 open -> openvt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 Apr 14 11:26 pidof -> /sbin/killall5
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root   34740 Nov  8 14:27 ping
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root   39116 Nov  8 14:27 ping6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   34420 Apr 13 17:35 plymouth
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4 Apr  3 17:58 rbash -> bash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4 Mar 10 15:57 rnano -> nano
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4 Mar 29 19:40 sh -> dash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4 Mar 10 15:57 sh.distrib -> dash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr 13 21:45 static-sh -> busybox
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root   31116 Apr  9 04:40 su
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root   67720 Mar 30 06:49 umo
```

I also included links.